# I am getting EOF error when I upload a code in codechef. How to solve this?

Tags: python, eoferror

I am getting EOF error when I upload a code in codechef. That same code is running nice without any error in online compilers and Pycharm. I don't know why I am getting this.

```py
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
if a[0]>a[1]:
    print(float(a[1]))
elif a[0]%5==0:
    print(float(a[1]-(a[0]+0.5)))
else:
    print(float(a[1]))
```

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: hello Mr.Darjusch. I mentioned the code above

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem with codechef..

Try the following:

```
try:
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
if a[0]>a[1]:
    print(float(a[1]))
elif a[0]%5==0:
    print(float(a[1]-(a[0]+0.5)))
else:
    print(float(a[1]))
except:
    pass
```

*It is a bit hacky but should solve the problem!*